# How to refresh page on goBack with React Navigation V5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to refresh page data when I navigate back to it.

Here I'm going back:

```
.then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
            console.log(responseData);
            this.renderResults(responseData)
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen');
            }, 100)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

when you go back you can add `focus` listener and refresh the data

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
function AppScreen({ navigation }) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      // The screen is focused
      // Call any action and update data
    });

    // Return the function to unsubscribe from the event so it gets removed on unmount
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);

  return <View />;
}
```

source : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/

Comment: I try that but I'm not sure what to put after ('focus', () => {})

Comment: So to put the API requests ?

Comment: you can request get data from server in there, actually when you change etch of state parameters Your screen reload and update. @YoanIvanov

Comment: Can you check what I'm doing wrong - https://snack.expo.io/VzGPK6!Ta

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `focus` listener, use the `useFocusEffect` hook which is designed for such use cases and provides a way to cleanup side-effects like `useEffect` does.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

function App({ navigation }) {
  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      let cleanedUp = false;

      fetch('https://your/api')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
          if (cleanedUp) {
            // Ignore the results if the effect is no longer valid
            // e.g. component was unfocused, not mounted anymore etc.
            return
          }

          console.log(responseData);
          renderResults(responseData);

          setTimeout(() => {
            navigation.navigate('HomeScreen');
          }, 100);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });

      return () => {
        cleanedUp = true;
      };
    }, [navigation])
  );

  // Your component code
}
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/#triggering-an-action-with-the-usefocuseffect-hook